# Image doesn't render on JS canvas with code inside onLoad();

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to program a simple game with JS with the main character as an image of a fish. However, I cannot get the image to load not matter what I try. I've looked up a few tutorials, but none of them work. I've read that I need to put the image code inside `onload();` so the `<img>` loads before it's called in JS. I tried that, but it still didn't work. I kept tweaking the code for a couple hours and came to come weird errors in the console like `drawImage();` is not defined. I'm stumped, but I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious because I'm fairly new to JavaScript. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fish Game</title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000; background: blue"></canvas>
<script>
var fishX = 400;
var fishY = 300;
var fishSpeed = 10;
var fishSize = 80;

 window.onload = function() {
        var framesPerSecond = 60;

        console.log("Page Loaded!");
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        setInterval(function img() {
        }, 1000/framesPerSecond);
        drawImage(img, 10, 10);

 }

var img = document.getElementById("fish");

document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '38' || '87') {
        // up arrow
        fishY = fishY + fishSpeed;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40' || '83') {
        // down arrow
        fishY = fishY + fishSpeed;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37' || '65') {
       // left arrow
       fishX = fishX + fishSpeed;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39' || '68') {
       // right arrow
       fishX = fishX + fishSpeed;
    }
}
</script>

<body>
<img src="fish.png" id="fish" width="80px"  >


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setInterval(function img() {
        }, 1000/framesPerSecond)` this does nothing 60 times a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**`drawImage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) is a method of `canvasContext` which was missing in the snippet.

```js
var fishX = 400;
var fishY = 300;
var fishSpeed = 10;
var fishSize = 80;

window.onload = function() {
  var framesPerSecond = 60;

  console.log("Page Loaded!");
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  setInterval(function img() {}, 1000 / framesPerSecond);
  canvasContext.drawImage(img, 10, 10);

}

var img = document.getElementById("fish");

document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

  e = e || window.event;

  if (e.keyCode == '38' || '87') {
    // up arrow
    fishY = fishY + fishSpeed;
  } else if (e.keyCode == '40' || '83') {
    // down arrow
    fishY = fishY + fishSpeed;
  } else if (e.keyCode == '37' || '65') {
    // left arrow
    fishX = fishX + fishSpeed;
  } else if (e.keyCode == '39' || '68') {
    // right arrow
    fishX = fishX + fishSpeed;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg" id="fish" width="80px" />
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000; background: blue"></canvas>
```

*Note:* `<canvas>` must be part of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: does canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d'); not define canvasContext?

Comment: Yes but method is not invoked as `canvasContext .drawImage...`